# converting elements in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, break, element

For a project, I'm trying to find the first 1 of a series of ones in a vector. For example, I have as input:

```
x1=[1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]
```

and I need as output:

```
Y1=[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]
```

So every time there is a 1 in the vector, all consequent ones need to be turned into zeroes.

I have the following code, but for some reason it just returns Y1 with exactly the same values as x1.

```
n=numel(x1);
Y1=zeros(n,1);
for i = 1:n
if x1(i) == 1
    Y1(i)= 1;
    for j = (i+1): n 
        if x1(j)== 1
            Y1(j)=0;
        elseif x1(j) == 0
            Y1(j)=0;
            i=j+1;
            break
        end
    end
elseif x1(i) == 0
    Y1(i)= 0;
end

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy with `diff`. No loops needed.

```
Y1 = [ x1(1) diff(x1)==1 ];
```

or equivalently

```
Y1 = diff([0 x1])==1;
```

---

*How this works*: [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) computes the difference of an element with respect to the preceding element. When that difference is 1, a new run of ones has begun. The first element requires special treatment.

Comment: @user2991702 Welcome :-) If you are new to Matlab, try do do things "vectorized" (as in my answer). There are many cases when a loop would be used in other languages but in Matlab it can be done more easily (and usually faster) with a few vectorized operations such as `diff`, `sum` etc.

Answer (score 0):

A generalization of the answer by @Luis for the case where your vectors don't just contain zeros and ones:

```
Y1 = diff([0 x1]) & x1 == 1
```

This checks whether the value is one, and whether it is different from the previous value.